# "Change the look" only has one theme option

Tags: sharepoint-online, theme

Clicking on "change the look" of a modern site opens the panel as normal, but the side panel only has the current theme, and no others. Where there used to be a list of about 12 different color themes, there is one: current theme. This is the case in two different tenants. Did I miss an announcement? Any suggestions on why only one theme is being displayed?

Comment: yeah looks like its broken, checked at my end. One tenant is fine, another is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this issue started appearing since yesterday.

As a workaround, for now, you can select your themes from the modern list/library pages and Site contents page. The themes are still there, just not visible at the moment because of a bug.

Good news is that MS is aware of the issue and will be fixing it.

You can monitor this issue on github issues list.

Also, to get a list of themes, you can use `Get-SPOTheme` or `Get-PnPTenantTheme` and it will list the available themes in your tenant.

Reference - [Modern Themes Broken](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/2434)